# How do I shown that $x_{n+1}=x_n/2 + 1$ converges to $2$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $\{x_n\}$ be a converging sequence such that

$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+1$$

Show that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $2$. I am lost I have no idea how to begin.

These are my questions so that I can better understand the problem.
What does $x_{n+1}$ tell me? What is $x_{n+1}$ significance in relation to $x_n$.

Comment: I cannot seem to follow what this post is trying to say. What does "f x n g" mean? I can't quite tell how the sequence is defined, is the $x_n$ in the denominator? What about that $+1$?

Comment: f x n g thats an error. The sequence {xn} is not in the denominator. The plus one is not in the denominator either.   x(n+1)= (1*{xn})/2) +1

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add math type. I'm gonna look that up.

Comment: No problem mate, glad to see Arpan has you taken care of :D

Comment: Prove its is bounded above by 2 and increasing

Comment: Check, if you can apply Banach fixed-point theorem and solve $x=\frac{x}2+1$.

Answer (score 4):

$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{x_n}{2} + 1 \to x_{n+1} - 2 = \dfrac{x_n-2}{2} = \dfrac{x_{n-1}-2}{4} = \cdots = \dfrac{x_1-2}{2^n} \to 0 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} \to 2$.

Comment: I do not understand how you determined  the x_{n-1} term  from      (xn-2)/2 =(x_{n-1}-2))/4.

Comment: It comes from the recursive formula and replacing $n$ by $n-1$ you get: $\dfrac{x_n-2}{2} = \dfrac{\dfrac{x_{n-1}-2}{2}}{2}$

Comment: Sure. Hope you find it useful....